# PrimeFaces block UI does not work when the component to be blocked is updated via AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, blockui

I have displayed some components in `<p:panel>` as follows.

```
<p:growl id="growl" />

<p:panel id="panel" header="New User" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <p:messages id="messages" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="FirstName: *" />
        <p:inputText id="firstName" required="true" label="FirstName">
            <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message for="firstName" />

        <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname: *" />
        <p:inputText id="surname" required="true" label="Surname"/>
        <p:message for="surname" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" 
                     style="margin:0" 
                     actionListener="#{testManagedBean.insert}" 
                     update="growl panel"/>
</p:panel>

<p:blockUI block="panel" trigger="saveBtn" />
```

When the given button is pressed, `<p:growl>` and `<p:panel>` need to be updated which is done through the `update="growl panel"` attribute of `<p:commandButton>`. `<p:panel>` doesn't block, in this case.

`<p:panel>` is blocked only when `update="growl panel"` is changed to `update="growl"` i.e when the panel is skipped from being updated.

Is there a way to make `<p:blockUI>` work? `<p:panel>` should be updated on pressing the command button.

Answer (score 6):

I have alternatively chosen the [PrimeFaces Extensions'](http://primefaces-extensions.github.io/) [`<pe:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf) that works well even after the component to block is updated by AJAX as follows.

```
<!--xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"-->

<h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/block-ui.css"/>

<pe:blockUI target="panel" 
            content="blockPanelContents" 
            widgetVar="blockUIWidget"/>

<h:panelGrid id="blockPanelContents" columns="2" class="block-contents">
    <h:graphicImage library="default" 
                    name="images/ajax-loader1.gif" 
                    class="block-ui-image"/>

    <h:outputText value="Sending data..." class="block-ui-text"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton id="saveBtn" update="growl panel" 
                 onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block();" 
                 oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock();" 
                 actionListener="#{testManagedBean.insert}" 
                 icon="ui-icon-check" value="Save"/>
```

The CSS classes used as indicated by `<h:outputStylesheet>`:

```css
.block-ui-image {
    margin-right: 12px; vertical-align: middle;
}

.block-ui-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.block-contents {
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: @Krishna : Yes I'm learning PrimeFaces (currently 4.0) on JSF (currently 2.2.6). All of them are just exemplary applications (not live, commercial). I must **not** say *I'm working with...* Instead I should say, *I'm just learning / practising* :)

Comment: Thats nice. we write few topics on primefaces here www.javabeat.net/tag/primefaces/ . This would be useful. have you worked on omnifaces?

Comment: Thank you very much for this link :) Yes I'm having OmniFaces in my application for a few functions until now.